# How to have the top bar (navbar) not obscure the image and scroll with it?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could get the black bar on the top of the page to appear, not obscure the image, but also scroll with the image? (I have attached pictures below)

Currently, the black bar is positioned as fixed, but it won't appear. I have tried using sticky and absolute, but they block the picture in the process.

Also, this is a course exercise, so I am limited to only basic HTML and CSS.

Thank you!!

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6bJk.png)

[What I have currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdass.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

      <head>
     <title>Exercise 2 Start</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

      </head>

      <body>

      <div class="container">

     <div class="brand">Yosemite</div>

     <div class="byline"><p>Irene <strong>Li</strong></p><p>2019</p>

      </div>

     <div class="box1">1</div>

     <div class="box2">2</div>

     <div class="box3">3</div>

     <div class="box4">4</div>

     <div class="box5">5</div>  

     <div class="box6">6</div>

     <div class="box7">7</div>

     <div class="box8">8</div>

     <div class="box9">9</div>

 </div>

 </body>

 </html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

*   {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;         
}

HTML, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
}


body {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-    serif;
    margin: 0px;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4,
.box5,
.box6,
.box7,
.box8,
.box9 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}


.box1 {
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0002_03.png);
    float: right;
}

.box2 {
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0000_01.png);
    float: left;
}

.box3 {
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0001_02.png);
    float: left;
}

.box4 {
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0003_04.png); 
    float: left;
}

.box5 {
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0005_06.png);  
    float: right;
}

.box6 { 
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0004_05.png); 
    float: left;
}

.box7 {
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0008_09.png); 
    float: right;
}

.box8 { 
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0007_08.png);  
    float: right;
}

.box9 {
    background-image:url(../img/Yosemite_0006_07.png); 
    float: left;
}

.brand {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    font-size:36px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 900px;
}

.byline {
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for this ?

Answer (score 1):

> In order to archive that, you need to use z-index. If you set box to 
>   z-index to 0 and brand z-index to 10. Then the brand will be on top of the boxes.

```css
*   {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;         
}

HTML, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
}


body {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-    serif;
    margin: 0px;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4,
.box5,
.box6,
.box7,
.box8,
.box9 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}


.box1 {
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900);
    float: right;
}

.box2 {
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900);
    float: left;
}

.box3 {
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900);
    float: left;
}

.box4 {
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900); 
    float: left;
}

.box5 {
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900);  
    float: right;
}

.box6 { 
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900); 
    float: left;
}

.box7 {
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900); 
    float: right;
}

.box8 { 
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900);  
    float: right;
}

.box9 {
    background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900); 
    float: left;
}

.brand {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
  z-index:20;
    font-size:36px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 900px;
}

.byline {
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="brand">Yosemite</div>
 <div class="byline">
  <p>Irene <strong>Li</strong></p>
  <p>2019</p>
 </div>
 <div class="box1">1</div>

 <div class="box2">2</div>

 <div class="box3">3</div>

 <div class="box4">4</div>

 <div class="box5">5</div>

 <div class="box6">6</div>

 <div class="box7">7</div>

 <div class="box8">8</div>

 <div class="box9">9</div>

</div>
```

I made a codepen: [Click here](https://codepen.io/lauritzz77/pen/GPayoQ)